# Discord.js slash command option

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im using WOKCommands, and want to make so you can only choice a voice channel. How can i do this?

```
options: [
        {
            name: 'channel',
            description: ' Voice channel in which you want to play your activity',
            required: true,
            type: discord_js_1.default.Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.CHANNEL
            
        },
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the channel type id's in the official [Discord documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channel-object-channel-types). With that given, you can specify specific channel types. In this example, channel_types: [2] = only voice channels.

```js
options: [
        {
            name: 'channel',
            description: ' Voice channel in which you want to play your activity',
            required: true,
            type: discord_js_1.default.Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.CHANNEL
            channel_types: [2]
        },
    ],
```

Hope This Helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can't put type of option as Voice Channel
as it's not a valid type but `channel` is
so in this case you can check if the type of channel is voice and give him an error message to provide a voice channel 
Example:

```js
let channel = interaction.options.getChannel(interaction.options.data[0].name);
if(channel.type !== "GUILD_VOICE") return interaction.channel.send({ content:"Please provide a valid voice channel" });
```

Comment: No problem ;) glad to help